# RESTful API, where to place the Authorization key

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication, api-key

I'm building an api, on Laravel framework, meant for portable devices. I have read plenty of articles on how to properly secure the data and the transfers.

These are the action that I am taking to secure:

1. Send the data to an `https` domain with `TLS`
2. Unique API key for each device
3. Unique Tooken that are being regenerated from time to time.
4. The tooken is used to encrypt the data, using `hmac-sha1`

So I got left 2 questions:

- Should I send the API key set in a header like `X-Authorization`? Or add it to all my POST/GET/PUT/DELETEs within the encrypted data with `hmac-sha1`?
- Any big difference between the 2 methods pointed above?

I mostly based on this tutorial: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/ And other question related to the issue on SO

P.S. If there is anything that you think I could improve, please let me know!

Comment: Take a look at [Designing a Beautiful REST+JSON API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WXYw4J4QOU) talk by Les Hazlewood ([here are the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/stormpath/rest-jsonapis)). Les Hazlewood as a Stormpath CTO and Apache Shiro PMC Chair knows a thing or two about security. Very nice talk.

Comment: FWIW, I believe this is more of a style issue than a security one. Either can be done securely.
Also, be careful of caching (by proxies among others).